Make \todo automatically set [inline] when called inside a box
I often write large documents collaboratively with colleagues of varying LaTeX skill levels.  Inevitably, one of the co-authors will end up importing the todonotes package and using \todo{...} in a box (possibly one created by some macro or environment):
\parbox{10cm}{\todo{foo}}

This breaks the build with a cryptic Float(s) lost error, confusing almost everyone.
The problem can be worked around by telling \todo to create an inline note rather than one in the margin:
\parbox{10cm}{\todo[inline]{foo}}

However, many of my co-authors don't know enough about LaTeX to know when it is necessary to use this workaround, and even those that do might end up forgetting to set the option when it is required.  We could use \setuptodonotes{inline} in the preamble to force all notes to be inline, but since the default margin notes are less intrusive, we'd prefer to use those when possible.
Is there some way of configuring or patching the todonotes package such that the \todo macro checks whether it is being called from within a box (or anywhere else a \marginpar wouldn't work), and if so, automatically applies the inline option for that particular invocation?

Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.
